# Trouble creating an appropriate XPath expression

Tags: xml, xpath

I've tried a lot to get to the item from the element below using XPath expression, but it seems a bit misleading to me.
The string I want to locate with XPath is

> Excel VBA User Forms videos | Excel VBA Forms Pt 1 - Drawing Forms

The XPath expression I tried is:

```
//h1[@class="gamma"]/text()
```

And my XML code is:

```
<div class="woVideoShowPost">

    <h1 class="gamma">
        Excel VBA videos | Excel VBA Part 2 - Writing Your First Macro
    </h1>

    <p class="woVideoPosted">
        Posted by 
        <a href="/videos/author/andrewgould.htm">Andrew Gould</a>
         on 10 May 2013
    </p>

    <p>VBA, or Visual Basic for Applications, is a powerful tool that you can use to automate Microsoft Excel. This video introduces you to the basics of writing code in the VB Editor, including how to create a new module, how to write a subroutine, some best practice guidelines for laying out your code and adding comments, and how to write simple VBA instructions. We'll also show you how to run the simple procedure that you'll write, and how to ensure that you can save your code and reopen the file which contains it.</p>

    <p></p>

    <div class="woVideoWrapper">
        <div class="woVideoWrapped">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7RVGdA9AhrY" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="woVideoShowTipTitle">You can increase the size of the video:</p>


    <div class="woVideoShowTip">

        <img alt="Full screen mode for YouTube" src="../../files/videos/images/youtube.jpg">
        <p>You can view the video in full screen mode as shown on the left, using the icon at the bottom right of the frame.</p>

    </div>

    <p class="woVideoShowTipTitle">You can also increase the quality of the video:</p>

    <div class="woVideoShowTip">

        <img alt="Changing resolution" src="../../files/videos/images/youtube2.jpg">
        <p>
            You can improve the resolution of the video using another icon at the bottom right of the frame.  This will slow down the connection speed,
            but increase the display and sound quality. This icon only becomes visible when you start playing the video.
        </p>

    </div>

    <p class="woVideoShowTipTitle">
        Finally, if nothing happens when you play the video, check that you're not using <a href="../../blog/s312/compatibility-view.htm">IE in compatibility view</a>.

    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your XPath expression looks OK: in what way does it "seem misleading"?

Comment: You clearly did something wrong, and I have no idea what. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your XPath expression with an XSLT-stylesheet and the result was that

```
"//h1[@class='gamma']"
```

**DID WORK**,
but the expression

```
"//h1[@class="gamma"]"
```

**DID NOT WORK**.

The simple difference is rooted in the type of quotes:

- In the first variant there are single quotes (`'`) around the string 'gamma'.
- And in the second variant there are double quotes (`"`) around the string "gamma", which will probably conflict with the surrounding quotes of your query.

So check the type of your quotes and you will probably solve your problem.

Comment: @SMth80: I do appreciate the courtesy of your comment and noticed the revision of my _edit_. I respect your decisions, but due to my lack of understanding them, I refrain from being involved further. So please respect this decision, too.